# Quickly delete all messages and comments by a given user in a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I'm an admin for a group on Facebook. A user has recently requested that all his content be removed from the group (he is no longer welcome to post to the group so I can't tell him to just remove the posts himself).

Is there a quick way to delete all of his posts (and comments)? I can delete them one by one but it'd take me ages. He's already been banned from the group, but I still see his posts. (Is it just because I'm an admin?)

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ Often asked but little known tricks (and thanks to facebook's API you can do a lot more than you think automatically) to delete a spammers comments from your statuses, go to the link above and choose FQL, get an access token and run the following query to get the ID of the user:

```
SELECT fromid, text from comment where object_id in (select status_id from status where uid=me())
```

Then use:

```
SELECT id from comment where object_id in (select status_id from status where uid=me() limit 0,100) and fromid=[id of user to delete comments]
```

or

```
SELECT id from comment where object_id in (select link_id from link where owner=me() limit 0,100) and fromid=[id of user to delete comments]
```

Then open your debugger console in the browser (usually F12) then fill in and paste the following javascript:

```
var acc=""; //put access token in here
var dat=""; //put data returned in here
for (var obj in dat.data) { var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/" + dat.data[obj].id + "?access_token=" + acc + "&format=json&method=delete&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1"); xhr.send(); xhr.responseText; }
```

Comment: FQL is deprecated, is it possible to replicate this technique in Graph api as well?

Answer (score 1):

As an admin you have access to the posts and members, irrespective of their ban in person.

You can put the name of him/her on the search in group "top right" and get the history, then delete the posts, with your admin power. But, You have to do it one by one (Facebook policy) or you have to wait until Facebook takes some action.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use facebook [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/feed) to delete bulk post.

get post id then delete that post by [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post) api

you can also use facebook graph explorer to delete temporary